# How to initialize an integer in a recursive function, only when the function is called from other functions?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I have written a function for calculating multiplication of 2 matrices.
This is the function :

```
int entrycal(int i,int j,int m,int n,int k,int a[m][n],int b[n][k],int q) {
static int sum = 0;
sum += a[i][q] * b[q][j];
if ( q+1 < n )
    entrycal(i,j,m,n,k,a,b,q+1);
return sum;
}
```

I have tried using     static int , but when I need to calculate a new entry (after returning sum and calling the function again from the main function ) ,it doesn't get initialized to zero.
I have solved the problem using a global variable "sum" and initializing it in the main function every time I call the "entrycal" function, but I like to solve it without using global variables.Is it possible ?

secondary question : 
If there is a problem with my function arguments and they can get better I would be happy to learn more!

sorry for my english

thanks

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't do this in a loop? It will be thousand times faster, consume less memory and be far more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question:

```
int entrycal(int i,int j,int m,int n,int k,int a[m][n],int b[n][k],int q) {
    static int sum = 0;
    int total_sum = 0;
    sum += a[i][q] * b[q][j];
    if ( q+1 < n )
        entrycal(i,j,m,n,k,a,b,q+1);
    total_sum = sum;
    sum = 0;
    return total_sum;
}
```

However I would implement it like:

```
int entrycal(int i,int j,int m,int n,int k,int a[m][n],int b[n][k],int q) {
    int sum = a[i][q] * b[q][j];
    if ( q+1 < n )
        return sum + entrycal(i,j,m,n,k,a,b,q+1);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was thinking about some middle variable !!